# Bash supress "Bad file descriptor" error message

Tags: bash, file-descriptors

I get the following error message when I try to write to a file descriptor when the other end has the fd closed before the writing:

```
./scr.sh: line 5: "$fd": Bad file descriptor
```

the code looks more or less like this:

```
f(){
    local fd=$1
    sleep 2
    if command >&"$fd"; then
        echo test >&"$fd" 2>/dev/null
    fi
}

coproc sleep 1
f "${COPROC[1]}"
```

Is there a way to either detect that the file descriptor is bad or just suppress the error message?

---

Edit:
so the solution suggested by @terdon to redirect to /dev/null command doesn't work since the error is generated by the echo, which already has that redirection

opted for the solution of Stephane to duplicate fds after running coproc

Edit2:

So I just figured out that the solution for duplicating the fds didn't really work as expected. I was running the command in a subshell so i just noticed that the test whether the "closed" fd can be duplicated always succeed and when the fd is actually closed the shell exits. I have minified the example above to illustrate the issue:

```
coproc sleep 1
exec {fd_in}<&"${COPROC[0]}"-
exec {fd_out}>&"${COPROC[1]}"-

sleep 2

if { >&"${fd_out}"; } 2<> /dev/null; then
    echo test >&"$fd_out" 2>/dev/null
fi
echo done #never reaches here
```

Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: If suppressing the error is enough, why don't you just send it to dev null as you do with your `echo`? Is `if command >&"$fd" 2>/dev/null; then` really all you need?

Comment: The problem is that bash *closes* the fd (and unsets `$COPROC`) as soon as the coproc dies. The fd could even have been reused for something else (like if you use process substitution in the interval), so you should check `$COPROC` directly not a copy of it and even that would be racy. Better avoid coproc altogether or make a copy of the coproc fds straight after running coproc so you know they would not be closed behind your back by bash.

Comment: @terdon, rather `command 2> /dev/null >&"$fd"`, but in any case, as I said above, the fd could be closed but also have been reused for something else.

Comment: See also [How do you use the command coproc in various shells?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/86270) (and the section about why they're not so popular).

Comment: `bash` even closes the reading COPROC fd even if the coproc has written something (try `bash -c 'coproc echo test; fd=${COPROC[0]}; sleep 1; cat <&"$fd"'` for instance), so looks like the coproc design is pretty broken in that shell. You may want to use zsh/ksh instead (which have had coproc for decades before bash).

Comment: ksh closes the writting fd, but not reading fd upon coproc termination. zsh closes neither.